# SSRS Removing percent sign and word "Percentage" on a pareto chart

Tags: ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I have a Pareto chart that I am trying to remove the "%" sign on the Y axis and the word "Percentage", but im not able to find the settings to remove or hide this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the Design tab, select the secondary axis, i.e, the axis with the percentages.

[image]

Be sure to deselect the `Show Axis Title` option, it will disappear the **Percentage** title.

Now go to `Secondary Vertical Axis Properties...` option.

Go to `Number` tab and select `Number` option. It will format the axis labels to show only numbers without `%`.